# Сортировка массива по алфавиту и по возрастанию чисел вида 1 000, 20 000 (т.е. с пробелом)

Tags: php

Как бы это сделать. Приведу пример. У нас есть массив:

```
array(
    'Обычный 1 000',
    'Обычный 500',
    'Обычный 2 000',
    'Большой',
    'Обычный 1 000 000',
    'Обычный 50 000'
)
```

А нужно расположить это в таком порядке:

```
array(
    'Большой',
    'Обычный 500',
    'Обычный 1 000',
    'Обычный 2 000',
    'Обычный 50 000',
    'Обычный 1 000 000'
 )
```

При этом нужно сохранить ключи. Тут явно нужно использовать функцию `uasort`. Но вот как составить колбэк `cmp_function` для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uasort потому, что нужно сохранить ключи в массиве.
Очень хорошо ответили на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641077/alphanumerical-array-sorting-caveat-spaces-as-a-thousands-separator-in-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

```
function cmp_function($a, $b){
    $a = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $a));
    $b = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $b));
    return $a - $b;
}
```

А чем вам usort не угодила?

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки + сохранение ключей, есть функция `asort($array);` или сортировка в другую сторону arsort($array);